# XPath collect multiple attributes (html events)

Tags: html, perl, xpath, xml-libxml

I have a section of html code, and am trying to parse it via Perl's XML::LibXML module. I am trying to collect all the events within the html (onclick, onchange, onsubmit, etc), and thought XPath would be useful for identifying them.  I know I can do

```
'//@onclick|//@onchange|//@onsubmit|...'
```

but was wondering if there's a way to avoid listing them, to ensure that no events are missed.  The only idea I had was

```
'//@on*'
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
'//@*[starts-with(name(), "on")]'
```

The

```
start-with()
```

and

```
name()
```

are some Xpath functions, check http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/ & http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: Then a) don’t word it as a question, and b) include explanation. The OP probably never heard about functions in XPath and at least the precise meaning of the two used should be mentioned. BTW a close parenthesis is missing.

Comment: Did you forgot the quotes? It looks like a comment.